# Value of type 'MKAnnotationView' has no member 'pinTintColor'?

Tags: xcode, mapkit, mkannotationview, xcode11.4, swift5

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }

    let identifier = "Annotation"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView!.pinTintColor = UIColor.redColor
    } else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation

    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Why I have error "Value of type 'MKAnnotationView' has no member 'pinTintColor'"?
I would like change color of pin from orange to blue without changing image.
I use swift 5.2 and xcode 11.4.1

Answer (score 0):

From the compiler's point of view, `annotationView` is a `MKAnnotationView?`, and nothing else. You can rewrite your check like so:

```
if annotationView == nil {
    let pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    pin.canShowCallout = true 
    pin.pinTintColor = UIColor.redColor
    annotationView = pin
}
```